# How do I make a blade layout

Tags: html, css

I want to make an application layout using "blades" as follows:

Blade height will always be 100VH.

Blade width will be variable.

Blades will be added and removed with js, starting with one, then adding one after another. After width runs out, the left side should scroll off-screen.

An example of this is the current Azure Portal. Each time you click an item, a new blade appears with more specific data about that item.

But I am not sure how to get started with this.  The closest I can think of is using bootstrap grid system, but the width will not necessary match the grid system used there. I don't even know if "blades" is the correct term, but that is what is used by the Azure team.

```
<div style="height: 100vh; background: greenyellow; width: 200px"></div>
<div style="height: 100vh; background: pink; width: 200px"></div>
```

The above should be side by side, with greenyellow on the left, and pink to the right of it. Instead of greenyellow above the pink.

Here is a screenshot of the Azure Portal. It has 3 "blades"

[image: Azure Portal]

Comment: Please Provide Your Trying Code

Comment: Ok, I will see if I can come up with something.

Comment: If you mean this http://epvpimg.com/41P0f I would call id cards in a Grid System

Comment: I get that sometimes it's hard to get started but a screen would help us to be able to help you. Please provide.

Comment: Screen shot provided.  @DestinatioN, that is the older Azure Portal

Answer (score 0):

I found the flexbox:

```
 <style>
    .flex-container {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        list-style: none;
        display: flex;
    }

    .flex-item {
        background: tomato;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 100vh;
        margin: 5px;
        line-height: 150px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 3em;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
<ul class="flex-container">
    <li class="flex-item">1</li>
    <li class="flex-item">2</li>
    <li class="flex-item">3</li>
    <li class="flex-item">4</li>
</ul>
```

[CSS Tricks on the Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)